# Adding values ​on the x axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I add the values ​​on the X axis so that they are from 1 to 16? Thank u for answer.

My code and result:

```r
ggplot(data, aes(education)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, aes(fill=income), color='black', position='fill') + scale_fill_manual(values = c("red","green"))
```

[image]

Comment: Try `+scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:16)`